# vRanger backups fail, repository does not contain enough free space

Tags: backup

Everything tells me that I just need to uncheck the option to check for free space, but I cannot find where that option lies within the program.  Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Almost zero detail here, no reference to any versions - what do you seriously expect?

Comment: I don't think vRanger is lying to you... your target datastore probably really doesn't have enough space.

Answer (score 1):

vRanger takes the maximum possible amount of data (sum of all VMDK’s) and compares it to space available regardless how much data is actually resides inside the VM.

Three possible solutions:

A)Free up more disk space on the drive with repository

B)Move repository/create new on another location. (Please edit the job and select new repository)

C)Edit the job and uncheck “Check destination for free space”

Answer (score 0):

When you create a job there is an option for this.